# What's "init" used for in swift?

Tags: swift, initialization, init, initializer

Is there difference ?  And the effect of deinit ?

struct mark {
       var mark: Int
}

struct mark {
       var mark: Int
       init(mark: Int) {
          self.mark = mark
       }
}

Comment: I would highly recommend you have a read of the [initialization section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) (In particular the "Memberwise Initializers for Structure Types" bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`init` is used to set initial values for properties on a `struct` or `class` type at the time it is created, before any other methods may be called on it and before it is passed as a parameter to other functions or methods.

In Swift, any non-optional properties must be set with initial values before `init` returns. Properties may be declared with initial values already, which excludes them from having to be set in an init method.

- `class` types must have an `init` method implemented if there are any non-optional properties not already declared with initial values.
- For `struct` types only, Swift will automatically generate an `init` method with parameters for each non-optional property that was not already declared with an initial value. You can optionally create any number of alternative `init` methods for the struct, as long as by the time each one returns, all non-optional properties have a value.
- In your example, there is no difference between the `init` method created on the second line, and the automatically created `init` method provided for that `struct` type by Swift. But you could create alternate initializers that, for example, take a `Double` instead of an `Int` and then convert it internally before setting the `mark` property.

I think the key point to realize is that even when you do not specify an `init` method yourself, one still exists, as created automatically by Swift for `struct` types. So in both line one and line two of your example, an `init` method is being called (and they are essentially identical implementations). The only difference is that *you* wrote the `init` implementation in the second line, and the Swift compiler writes the `init` method in the first line.

`deinit`only exists for `class` types, which are passed by reference and have memory management. Any `deinit` method you declare on a `class` you create will be called when there are no more references to that instance of the `class` and it will be released from memory. It's used to deregister from various observation patterns or otherwise clean up right before the instance is destroyed.